# PHP not seeing mysql.sock from the web

Tags: php, mysql

I have a script that connects to a MySQL database in localhost,  when I run it from the console it runs just fine, but when I run it from the web, I get this:

```
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in /var/www/html/tests/mysql.php on line 3
```

Error: Unable to connect to MySQL. Debugging errno: 2002 Debugging error: No such file or directory

I checked my php.ini file and it has the correct location of mysql.sock, the file exist, but php won't connect via web.

Also, I have Fedora Linux with Firewall disabled as well as SELinux, so I have no idea what can be causing this.

This is the test code I'm using:

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "password", "my_db");

if (!$link) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}

echo "Success: A proper connection to MySQL was made! The my_db database is great." . PHP_EOL;
echo "Host information: " . mysqli_get_host_info($link) . PHP_EOL;

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Post an example of your code that demonstrates this issue.

Comment: What code is on line 3? Don't post your code as a comment, edit your question and mark it as code so it displays correctly.

Comment: As you can see there is nothing on line 3, sorry about the comment, I didn't know it was going to do that.

Comment: I have mysql configured so the mysql.sock file is at /tmp/mysql.sock, my php.ini also has that same info in it.

Comment: What web server are you using? Did you check both the command line `php.ini` and the web server `php.ini`?

Comment: You could also make a `info.php` page that just has `<?php phpinfo();` in it and make sure your php running from you web server is pointing to the right sock file.

Comment: I'm using Apache, I did, the script shows me the success line via CLI and php.ini is the same for web server as I can see the line in phpinfo();

Comment: who is the owner of the .sock file and what are the permissions on it? apache will be trying to access it as probably as user `www-data`

Comment: the file owner is mysql, and it has 777 permissions.

Comment: Also just for fun try `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` it could be an issue with name resolution.

Comment: I thought of that too, it works just fine using TCP (IP address) and my /etc/hosts file has 127.0.0.1 as localhost

Comment: So it works correctly when you use `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: That is correct, but not when I use localhost.

Comment: Might be a routing problem on the server it self. This might be a question for the linux/unix site.

Comment: What OS are you running this on? agree with @MathieudeLorimier though at this point we know it isn't a coding issue it is a server setup issue. Would probably better to ask on Server Fault.